# how to select excel range in vb6 that has multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vb6

I am having an array of 70000 elements(vb6) and I need to place the array as an excel column.
Since each excel sheet has row limit of 66k I can't do it.

I tried selecting the range with multiple worksheets but I am getting error.

Comment: Is is a string array (single dimension) or a 2D array already suitable for dumping to Excel? In either case you will need to resize the array to fit into 2 columns.

Comment: how to resize the arrays ? lets say i need to put the 30000 rows in first sheet and rest on the next

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`Updated Code #1`**

The code at top has been updated to

- clearly separate the creation of the sample 70K array from the the interaction with Excel
- to use two new arrays to separate the sample 70k array rather than one (note `ObjExcel.Transpose` can't be used as a workaround to recuce the first dimension of the initial array as there are more than 65536 records in `X`)
- leave the automated Excel instance open at the end of the code
- test for the presence of at leat two Excel sheets (as per Doug's comment)

I have added an alternative code that dumps the initial 70K to a worksheet, then sets the 30K and 40K directly from the worksheet without looping (see *`Updated Code #2`*)

```
     Sub SplicedArray2()
    Dim objExcel As Object
    Dim objWB As Object
    Dim X(1 To 70000, 1 To 1) As String
    Dim Y()
    Dim Z()
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngRow2 As Long
    Dim lngStart As Long

    'create intial 70K record array
    For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
        X(lngRow, 1) = "I am record " & lngRow
    Next

    'records split size
    lngStart = 30000

    Set objExcel = CreateObject("excel.application")
    'creats a new excel file. You may wish to open an existing one instead
    Set objWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Add

    ReDim Y(1 To UBound(X, 1) - lngStart, 1 To 1)
    'Place records 30001 to 70000 from original array to second array
    For lngRow2 = 1 To UBound(Y, 1)
        Y(lngRow2, 1) = X(lngRow2 + lngStart, 1)
    Next lngRow2

    ReDim Z(1 To lngStart, 1 To 1)
    'Place records 1 to 30000 from original array to third array
    For lngRow2 = 1 To UBound(Z, 1)
        Z(lngRow2, 1) = X(lngRow2, 1)
    Next lngRow2

    'Test for presence of second sheet, add it if there is only one sheet
    If objWB.Sheets.Count < 2 Then objWB.Sheets.Add
    'Dump first set of records to sheet 1
    objWB.Sheets(1).[a1].Resize(UBound(Y, 1), UBound(Y, 2)) = Y
    ' Dump second set of records to sheet 2
    objWB.Sheets(2).[a1].Resize(UBound(Z, 1), UBound(Z, 2)) = Z
    objExcel.Visible = True

    'close file (unsaved)
    ' objWB.Close False
    ' objExcel.Quit
    ' Set objExcel = Nothing
    End Sub
```

**`Updated Code #2`**

```
    Sub OtherWay()
   'Works only in xl 07/10 if more than 65536 rows are needed
    Dim objExcel As Object
    Dim objWB As Object
    Dim objws As Object
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngStart As Long
    Dim X(1 To 70000, 1 To 1) As String
    Dim Y()
    Dim Z()

    Set objExcel = CreateObject("excel.application")
    'Add a single sheet workbook
    Set objWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Add(1)
    Set objws = objWB.Sheets.Add

    For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
        X(lngRow, 1) = "I am record " & lngRow
    Next

    'records split size
    lngStart = 30000

    With objws.[a1]
        .Resize(UBound(X, 1), UBound(X, 2)).Value2 = X
        Y = .Resize(lngStart, UBound(X, 2)).Value2
        Z = .Offset(lngStart, 0).Resize(UBound(X, 1) - lngStart, UBound(X, 2)).Value2
        .Parent.Cells.ClearContents
    End With

    objWB.Sheets(1).[a1].Resize(UBound(Y, 1), UBound(Y, 2)) = Y
    objWB.Sheets(2).[a1].Resize(UBound(Z, 1), UBound(Z, 2)) = Z
    objExcel.Visible = True

    'close file (unsaved)
    ' objWB.Close False
    ' objExcel.Quit
    ' Set objExcel = Nothing
    End Sub
```

**`Original Code`**

Something like this will do it

1. The code creates an 60,000 record 2D array from the cells in A1:A6000
2. It then uses a second array to store the second half (30001 to 60000) of the records of the first array
3. The first half of the records in the original array (1 to 30000) are dumped to the first sheet (the remaining records are simply ignored as the Excel range is half the array size)
4. The second array is dumped to the second sheet

The code below uses `INT()` to handle arrays with odd records
ie 60001 records would be dumped

- record 1 to 30000 to sheet1
- records 30001 to 60001 to sheet 2

***[Update code to show automation of Excel]***

```
    Sub SplicedArray()
    Dim objExcel As Object
    Dim objWB As Object
    Dim X()
    Dim Y()
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngStart As Long

    Set objExcel = CreateObject("excel.application")
    'creats a new excel file. You may wish to open an existing one instead
    Set objWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Add

    'create 60000*1 array from column A
    X = objWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A60000").Value2

    'determine if second array needs X/2+1 records for an odd sized array
     If UBound(X, 1) Mod 2 <> 0 Then
        ReDim Y(1 To Int(UBound(X, 1) / 2) + 1, 1 To 1)
    Else
        ReDim Y(1 To Int(UBound(X, 1) / 2), 1 To 1)
    End If

    'loop from 30001 to 60000
    For lngRow = Int(UBound(X, 1) / 2) + 1 To UBound(X, 1)
        ' put value of row 30001 column 1 into row 1 column 1 of second array
        ' ......
        ' put value of row 60000 column 1 inro row 30000 column 1 of second array
        Y(lngRow - Int(UBound(X, 1) / 2), 1) = X(lngRow, 1)
    Next lngRow
    ' Dump first half of records from orginal array to sheet 1
    objWB.Sheets(1).[a1].Resize(Int(UBound(X, 1) / 2), UBound(X, 2)) = X
    ' Dump second half of records from new array to sheet 2
    objWB.Sheets(2).[a1].Resize(UBound(Y, 1), UBound(Y, 2)) = Y

    'close file (unsaved)
    objWB.Close False
    objExcel.Quit
    Set objExcel = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Comment: The guts of your code work fine, but as an example it's hard for me to follow:  Why is this done in a new, invisible, instance of Excel and then closed without saving?  The first sheet still has 60,000 rows of data when it's done (I stopped and added data to Sheet1 after it was created).  Also for people (like me) who only open a book with one sheet, it needs to add a second.  Finally, it would be nice if it dealt with the 70,000 item array @jeyaganesh mentioned.  Sorry to be so picky!

Comment: @dougglancy the question was asked in vb as opposed to vba and the existing 2D array may well have come externally to Excel, so my focus was showing how to split one array into 2 for dumping into 2 sheets for an automated Excel instance. I had to create an array from somewhere for demonstration which is all the initial data filling of 'X' is intended for - I hadn't meant to delete the "extra" records but I can see why that has caused a query. I will add code to check for a second sheet as per your comment

Comment: @dougglancy . I trimmed the array to 60k when I read the "30K on the first sheet" comment as I thought a method to split the array in half for any data size may be more useful than a simple subtraction. I will provide an alternative to spli the 70K into 30k and 40k plus use transponse to actually trim the first array. Thanks for your comments

Comment: Two things to fix: 1) There's a typo "ojbwb" that leads to an undeclared variable.  2) The check for the 2nd sheet needs to happen before dumping Z back in (or need to add the 2nd sheet to end of ObjWB, I think), otherwise the Y data is dumped over the Z data. Otherwise it's fast and clear, and I appreciate the separating out of the original array creation.  Makes it transportable!

Comment: @DougGlancy ouch!. Have fixed these issues and added a non-loop alternative to generate the two sub-arrays.

Comment: Yikes!  You've crossed your Y's and Z's in the last couple of lines, leading to 10k rows of #NA's in Sheet2 and records up to only 60,000 in Sheet1.  Also, the assignment of X to a range won't work with 66k rows in XL2003, which was the original problem :).  Tell me if I should shut up!

Comment: @dougglancy {sigh} that is payback for me changing the order after testing. I will fix the YxZ. On the second point I was showing that Excel itself can be used to set sub arrays and that this is a workaround when `Transpose` can't be used for more than 65536 rows .. But I should have been clearer that this can't be applied to this particular question

Comment: Alright, let's call it a day (or whatever it is now on your end of the world).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6218/discussion-between-brettdj-and-doug-glancy)